# Mocking default values for return types with mockito + specs2

Tags: scala, playframework, mockito, specs2

Given a mock:

```
val myMock = mock[SomeClass]
```

I am trying to set it up so that the mock returns default values for various types. E.g. for things that returns `String`, it would return `""`.

I discovered [`RETURNS_SMART_NULLS`](http://mockito.googlecode.com/svn/branches/1.7/javadoc/org/mockito/Mockito.html#RETURNS_SMART_NULLS) which looks like it works for basic return types like String. Here is how I am using it in Scala / Specs2:

```
val myMock = mock[SomeClass].settings(smart = true)
```

Now to the problem: since I am using Scala, my code / APIs do not return nulls but return Option values. So what I am trying to do is get the mock to default to returning a non null value for Option return types: either `None` (preferred), or `Some[T]` where T is the type in the container (if its String, then `Some("")`).

So for example if `SomeClass` has an attribute `address` of type `Option[String]`, how can I configure mockito to return `None` when `myMock.address` invoked instead of null. These nulls are causing downstream errors.

Note, its *not* a viable solution for me to specifically mock the behavior of *each* of these individual invocations (e.g: `myMock.address returns None`)

Comment: It's not viable to wire them up, even if you use [argument matchers](http://site.mockito.org/mockito/docs/current/org/mockito/Mockito.html#argument_matchers)?

Comment: Thats a valid question. With my current setup, its not. But this may be a bigger indicator of an architectural flaw: basically, I am unit testing Controllers in Play Framework. These controllers then pass on these mocked objects to the views, which in turn, use the mocks many times. So its not viable for me to wire up every possible invocation of the mock by the view. Comments on this setup in general would be appreciated too. Ideally I'd like to somehow isolate the view from the test, but I haven't figured out how to do that.

Comment: I don't know how to relate it to Mockito return types, but if you wrap all incoming values in another `Option` and then `.flatten` them, you will always get either a `None` or a `Some`. I.e. `Option(Option(null)).flatten == None`.

Comment: It would be nice if there were some way to wire it up based on the _return type_ rather than the call itself: e.g. "for every call that would return an Option, give back a None, regardless of what the call is"; e.g. no reference at all to what was invoked.

Comment: I see what you're saying, but that would require a lot of added boilerplate in my actual code (e.g. my views). This would make it a lot harder to read and frankly a bit strange (at least to someone who's just reading my code out of context).

Comment: Perhaps you can use the [`InjectMocks`](http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/1.9.5/org/mockito/InjectMocks.html) annotation. Otherwise, I think you will have to step up the chain to real dependency injection, like Guice.

Comment: There is a method `public static <T> T mock(java.lang.Class<T> classToMock, Answer defaultAnswer)` that appears to do what you want.

Comment: Yes I actually came across that too. But I wasn't able to figure out how to get it to return a default value for a given type, e.g. return None for Option return types.  It looked like, to me, that it still required specifying a specific method / argument call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to test this class:

```
class Timers(i: Int, s: String) {
  def returnOption: Option[Int] = Some(i)
  def returnString: String = s
}
```

with this test:

```
import org.specs2.mutable.Specification
import org.junit.runner.RunWith
import org.specs2.runner.JUnitRunner
import org.mockito.Mockito._
import org.mockito.stubbing.Answer
import org.mockito.invocation.InvocationOnMock

@RunWith(classOf[JUnitRunner])
class TimersSpec extends Specification {

  val m = mock(classOf[Timers], new Answer[Any]() {
        def answer(inv: InvocationOnMock) = {
          inv.getMethod.getReturnType match {
            case c if c == classOf[Option[_]] => None
            case c if c == classOf[String] => ""
            case _ => null
          }
        }
      })

  "A mock timer" should {
    "return a None" in {     
      m.returnOption must beNone
    }
    "return a empty string" in {
      m.returnString mustEqual ""
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: thank you. worked perfectly (with slight modification to work with specs2)

Comment: Yeah i copied a runner that used gerkin-based tests, so it may be a bit strange. Glad it's working out