# Implicit options mock with mockito in scala

Tags: json, scala, mocking, mockito, scalatest

I have a case class that consists of some Options. Let's say

```
case class Clazz(field: Option[String] = None)
```

I'm trying to mock this class in a scalatest spec to pass to another function. Like...

```
val clazz = mock[Clazz]
```

It makes field a `null`.

Later this clazz is getting serialized into JSON with [circe.io](https://github.com/circe/circe) library and of course it fires an error: `scala.MatchError: null`. Because it expects option to be either `Some` or `None`.

So my question is... How can I force [mockito](http://site.mockito.org/) to use None for Options instead of just nulls. Seems like it needs some sort of implicit stuff.

Or maybe totally different approach?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried defaulting those fields to `None`? `case class Clazz(field: Option[String] = None)`

Comment: Yes. They're all defaulted to None. Sorry for not mentioning it.

Answer (score 0):

See: [Mocking default values for return types with mockito + specs2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28330729/mocking-default-values-for-return-types-with-mockito-specs2)

In ScalaTest, with `org.scalatest.mockito.MockitoSugar` the syntax is like:

```
val mockEth = mock[Clazz](new Answer[Any] { ... } )
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to define what will be the answer. At least I don't know such built-in functionality in mockito. It can be done in this way, when your test class extends `org.scalatest.mockito.MockitoSugar`:

```
// Configurated mock
val clazzMock = mock[Clazz]
when(clazzMock.field).thenReturn(None)
println(s"Configurated mock. Field: ${clazzMock.field}")

// Non-configurated mock
println(s"Non-configuarted mock. Field: ${mock[Clazz].field}")
```